# Express.js Run passport.authenticate() middlware and forward to 404 Handler

Tags: express, passport.js

```
app.post("/auth/login", isNotLoggedIn, Validator("login"), (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate(
    "local",
    { session: false },
    (authError, user, info) => {
      if (authError || !user) {
        return next(authError);
      }
      return req.login(user, { session: false }, (loginError) => {
        if (loginError) return next(loginError);

        const token = jwt.sign(
          { id: user.id, name: user.name, email: user.email },
          process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
          { expiresIn: "1h", issuer: "issuer" }
        );

        return res.status(200).json({
          ok: true,
          token,
        });
      });
    }
  )(req, res, next);
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const error = new ExpressError(
    `${req.method} ${req.url} doesn't exist`,
    404
  );
  next(error);
});
```

If you send a POST request to '/auth/login' according to the above code, the following error occur..

error: Error: POST /auth/login doesn't exist.

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

It seems to call up to 404 handler after login middleware runs.

How to solve this error?

Given that this error does not occur for other middleware, it seems to be an error that occurs only with the passport.authenticate() middleware. Also, when i erase the 404 handler from the code, no errors occur.